# Why can't I install local deb files properly

Tags: apt, package-management, ssh

I need to make a list of deb files, which allows me to install things without Internet.

As we know, when we execute `apt-get install XXX`, we can find some deb files at `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. With these deb files, we can execute `apt install ./*.deb` to do the installation locally (without Internet).

So here is what I've done:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg1
sudo apt-get install pkg2
...
...
sudo cp /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb ~/deb/
```

Now, I get all necessary deb files in `~/deb`.

Then, I copy `~/deb` to another new Ubuntu 16.04.3 and execute `apt install ./deb/*.deb`.

To my surprise, I found some weird errors:

1) Some debs conflict. For example, when I execute `apt install ./deb/*.deb`, it says that `a.deb` and `b.deb` conflict, I have to remove one of them to finish the installation.

2) After executing `apt install ./deb/*.deb`, the ssh of system is broken, I have to execute `apt update && apt install openssh-server openssh-client` to repair it.

I can't understand why the deb files coming from official source can't be installed locally properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For local files you can use **dpkg** or **gdebi**.

E.g. `dpkg -i /path/to/file.deb`

Or

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
gdebi /path/to/file.deb
```

Comment: Are you sure? I was told that `dpkg` was dangerous because it can't find the dependencies packages automatically while installing, this is why I use `apt install ./*.deb`.

Comment: If dependencies aren't found, you will get a warning and a suggestion to run `sudo apt-get install -f`. Run that, then run your **dpkg** command again just to make sure.